# screeps.com: simple script not working, issue with bi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, screeps

I get the following error from the console: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined", it has something to do with the array but I cannot find the mistake.

```
module.exports =
{
    create_creeps: function() 
    {

        var aHarvester  = [[TOUGH,TOUGH, MOVE, CARRY, WORK, MOVE]["harvester"]];

        Spawn.prototype.createMyCreep = function(aCreep,sRole) {
            if (!Game.spawns.Spawn1.spawning){

                var nameCount = 0;
                var name = null;
                while(name == null)
                {
                    nameCount++;
                    var tryName = sRole + nameCount;
                    if(Game.creeps[tryName] == undefined)
                        name = tryName;
                }
                var dbg= this.canCreateCreep(aCreep, name);
                if(dbg  == OK) {
                    console.log("Creating creep " + sRole);
                    return this.createCreep(aCreep , name,{ role:sRole });
                } else {
                    console.log("error "+dbg+" "+sRole);
                }
            } 
        };

        Game.spawns.Spawn1.createMyCreep(aHarvester[0],aHarvester[1][0]);

    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please separate arrays with a comma

So

```
[[TOUGH,TOUGH, MOVE, CARRY, WORK, MOVE]["harvester"]]
```

Should be

```
[[TOUGH,TOUGH, MOVE, CARRY, WORK, MOVE],["harvester"]]
```